# How to get error string returned from api when using deferred object?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, deferred

I am sending a post request to an API using retrofit 2. I am using a deferred object as the return type of the function

```
@POST("/some_path/")
fun sendPostReqAsync(@Body body: PostRequestBody): Deferred<PostReqResponse>
```

Here PostReqResponse is a DataClass and I am using Moshi as the convertor factory. 
When the req is successful then I am getting the required result. When there are errors on the API side it sends errors in response like "invalid argument" or "user does not exist".

```
{"non_field_errors":["User does not exist."]}
```

But by using try-catch I just get `"retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request."`

```
uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = onboardingApi.sendPostReqAsync(body).await()
                Log.i("api_data",response.toString())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                val error = e.toString()
                Log.i("api_data",error)
            }
        }
    }
```

But I want the error string returned by the API.
Can someone please tell me how to get that error string?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, i solved it by parsing the Json that obtained from Exception.

Here the solution that might be solve your problem

```
uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = onboardingApi.sendPostReqAsync(body).await()
                Log.i("api_data",response.toString())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                if (e is HttpException) {
                    val jsonObj = JSONObject(e.response()?.errorBody()!!.charStream().readText())
                    val error = jsonObj.getJSONArray("non_field_errors").getJSONObject(0).toString()
                    Log.i("api_data",error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```